# How to append text to contact form field

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me with the function with which I can display the product name, in this case, LEU CHROM in the input text field, the function would be included in the product_item.

This is the field on which I click and run the function

```
                        <div class="product__item" onclick="displayAbo()" id="product-medium" tabindex="-1" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-describedby="medium-desc">
                          <div class="product__inner" id="medium-desc">
                            <h3 class="product__title">TEST</h3>
                            <ul class="product__features">
                              <li class="product__features-item">40 Mbit/s</li>
                              <li class="product__features-item"><img src="themes/zuerich/images/I.png" style="width: 100px; margin-right: 110px;"></li>
                            </ul>
                            <h4 class="product__price">CHF 39.–</h4>
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

In this field, I want to insert text from the product_title class

```
<input class="contactFormClass_text" id="contactFormFieldId_382" type="text" name="contactFormField_382" value="">
```

This is a function with which I tried to display the date in the field as a test, but I could not get any more

```
  function displayAbo() {
   document.getElementById("contactFormFieldId_382").innerHTML = Date();
}
```

thanks to everyone who wants to help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
   document.getElementById("contactFormFieldId_382").value = document.querySelector('.product__title').textContent;
```

```html
<div class="product__item" onclick="displayAbo(this)" id="product-medium" tabindex="-1" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-describedby="medium-desc">
  <div class="product__inner" id="medium-desc">
    <h3 class="product__title">LEUWIN M</h3>
    <ul class="product__features">
      <li class="product__features-item">40 Mbit/s</li>
      <li class="product__features-item"><img src="themes/zuerich/images/I.png" style="width: 100px; margin-right: 110px;"></li>
    </ul>
    <h4 class="product__price">CHF 39.–</h4>
  </div>
</div>


<input class="contactFormClass_text" id="contactFormFieldId_382" type="text" name="contactFormField_382" value="">
```

Use class of the h3 to access value

Comment: Is it possible to show the class product__price additionally in the field?
eg: LEUWIN M CHF 39.-

Comment: Yes possible try `document.getElementById("contactFormFieldId_382").value = document.querySelector('.product__title').textContent+document.querySelector('.product__price').textContent;`

Comment: to do it, but if I have more of these products, then I do not work

Comment: I found the solution, look right You are :) thanks a lot for helping you

Comment: If you have more products, You should iterate over the elements using class and use `this` keywork to find the price,title for each div block.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the `value` property. That is:

```
function displayAbo() {
    document.getElementById("contactFormFieldId_382").value = Date();
}
```

Comment: it should not show me the date, but the name of this product, I want to display this <h3> element

Comment: Well, your mistake was to use `innerHTML` instead of `value`. As for product title, @misorude provided you a full example. So don't forget to vote and accept it as best answer.

Comment: Is it possible to show the class product__price additionally in the field?
eg: LEUWIN M CHF 39.-

Answer (score 0):

Pass the reference to the clicked element to the function, and then select the element with class `product__title` inside of it:

```js
function displayAbo(elem) {
   document.getElementById("contactFormFieldId_382").value = 
     elem.querySelector('.product__title').innerText;
}
```

```html
<div class="product__item" onclick="displayAbo(this)" id="product-medium" tabindex="-1" role="radio" aria-checked="false" aria-describedby="medium-desc">
  <div class="product__inner" id="medium-desc">
    <h3 class="product__title">LEUWIN M</h3>
    <ul class="product__features">
      <li class="product__features-item">40 Mbit/s</li>
      <li class="product__features-item"><img src="themes/zuerich/images/I.png" style="width: 100px; margin-right: 110px;"></li>
    </ul>
    <h4 class="product__price">CHF 39.–</h4>
  </div>
</div>


<input class="contactFormClass_text" id="contactFormFieldId_382" type="text" name="contactFormField_382" value="">
```

Comment: Is it possible to show the class product__price additionally in the field?
eg: LEUWIN M CHF 39.-

Comment: Sure - just read it the same way we did for the `product__title` element, and concatenate both with a space character in the middle, and assign that as the value of the input field.